# I do not know what we call this part of sentence: "to be deceiving"

Tags: syntax, functions

For example:

> It is like to be deceiving the whole nation.

Inside above sentence, what do we say the part "to be deceiving"? Does it have any specific name?

As I know about this:

> Is there anything to be shared?

In above sentence "to be shared" is called Passive infinitive.

Comment: At least in this sentence, "It is like deceiving the whole nation." just sounds better - could you try to think of another example where you need to include the "to be"?

Comment: It not only sounds better, it is right. Otherwise you get: It's, like, to be deceiving the whole nation.

Comment: As others have mentioned, your example does not sound like correct English and so would not have a "name".  Do you have a source for this example?

Comment: Some sub-dialects of English use "like to be -ing" to suggest intentionality or imminence. "He's like to be getting a dog" means he intends to or is about to get a dog.

Comment: Well, there are examples of using to be+ing form of verb; for example: She has to be asking for permission, It seems to be happening a big war between those countries, it happens to be learning more than in previous class, etc.

Comment: @StephenS It could make sense if it's part of a larger sentence. "Then he found out what it is like to be deceiving the whole nation".

Comment: This sounds like an archaic way of saying _This is likely to be deceiving the whole nation_ or _It is probable that this is deceiving the whole nation_

Comment: "She has to be asking for permission" is OK (to express obligation or necessity) because "have" must be followed by a to-infinitive in such cases, but "It seems to be happening a big war between those countries" and "it happens to be learning more than in previous class" are not idiomatic. When used with the dummy pronoun "it", both "it seems" and "it happens" are followed by "that", subject, and predicate ("It seems that a big war was happening...", "It happens that we are learning more...")

Answer (score 0):

This is just an infinitive. You could call it the [continuous infinitive](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/continuous-infinitive/). It is used when an infinitive is needed, and the meaning refers to the (temporary) state, rather than an action.

Very often there is very little difference in meaning between the infinitive and the continuous infinitive, but sometimes it is required. Compare,

> I happened to be waiting for the bus when the accident occurred.
>   I happened to wait for the bus when the accident occurred.
>   *I happened waiting for the bus when the accident occurred. (ungrammatical)

We want to indicate that the "wait" was ongoing at the time of the accident. But the "happened to ..." construction requires us to use an infinitive. And so only the first sentence works. The second suggests that the wait started and finished during the accident (odd).  The last is ungrammatical.